# How do I run two different webservers from my django project with gunicorn?

Tags: django, deployment, grpc, gunicorn

My django project has a webserver, which I run with gunicorn. Now, I have also developed a gRPC-server, which I also need to deploy, preferrably also with gunicorn.
The gRPC server has a different entrypoint, e.g. within `myapp.management.grpc_downloader` there's the class `GRPCDownloader and that has a method` run_server()`. I somehow need to hand this method to gunicorn, in such a way that I can run this as a separate service in systemd, or in Docker once I containerize this.

How do I achieve this? Do I just write a second `wsgi.py` file, e.g. `wsgi_grpc.py`? And what should I write in there? The current one was automatically generated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was really simple: Don't run a second service with the wsgi server. The wsgi server keeps serving the web application as before. The gRPC server is started in a management command. A shell script executes this management command. This shell script is then passed to cron or executed inside a container.